# Why does the monitor fade on my HP Pavilion dv6?

Tags: display, laptop-repair, hp-pavilion

When I turn on my HP Pavilion DV6 it starts normally. Windows (win7) is loaded and a few seconds after that the screen fades. It doesn't go completely black, it fades to 99% black. External monitor plugged in works normally.

**What I have done so far is:**

1. Installed Linux on the laptop. The same problem
2. Installed Win 7 32b again, installed all updates + latest drivers. The same problem
3. Entered BIOS and restored to default settings. The same problem
4. Updated BIOS from ver. 14 to 18. The same problem
5. Run diagnostic tools. In the BIOS diagnostic log, there is error 0106 repeating many times. Couldn't find what it means.
6. Removed the battery. The same problem

I noted that when going into BIOS the screen fades as well, and as it is the same with Linux, I think the problem cannot be drivers, updates or OS related.
Another thing is that when I toggle windows button + 'P' and set it to projector only, the screens turns completely black (as it should) and when I set it to 'duplicate screen' the laptop screen starts working again for a couple of seconds and fades to 99% black again.

Why is this happening?

Comment: +1 Good job describing what you've already done to try to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: It sounds like it could be the backlight going. Unfortunately there's no easy way to test it unless you know someone with the same model who wouldn't mind you swapping the screens over.

Comment: Hmm I know a guy with another model HP laptop, the motherboard is dead. It is a 17 inches, but might worth trying to connect his monitor (if it has the same plugs) and isolate the problem. Good idea, I will try on monday and will come back. Have a nice weekend

Comment: No luck, totally different plugs ....

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much isolated it to being a hardware issue. Because you said this happens in BIOS, Windows 7, Linux and an external monitor works normally, I am inclined to believe the graphics adapter is good, but the LCD and/or it's components (back-light, inverter, etc) are starting to fail.

Not sure which diagnostic tools you ran, but you may want to try running [HP's Support Assistant](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01443317&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&product=4057208#N1098) which gives you specific categories to troubleshoot and can help you find the problem.

[image]

Comment: thanks for promt reply, downloading now. Hopefully it will show something.

Comment: no luck, it doesn't find any problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Just in case there is still anyone looking into this problem, there are some pretty serious issues with the video card on the motherboards of the DV6 as well as countless others. *It is a simple fix ONCE YOU TAKE THE WHOLE THING APART and heat up the area around the video chip for a SHORT period of time*. You need to lookup a repair video on youtube or elsewhere that will show you how to take apart the computer to do a reflow on the chip connections. Here is one video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSCb_ZjdpLk . There are some that claim that you can do it by just using a hair dryer on high. I personally am trying that one tomorrow. If I don't post again here then the hair dryer worked. If it doesn't I will be following the above video. Please by all means do a youtube search and find a video that you like that is easy and informative enough to allow you to feel comfortable to make the repair. Also, you MUST be careful not to heat it to long or damage any of the other components. Anything you do to your computer is a risk. Good Luck. :)

Comment: This isn't really a solution to the question.  It's more of a long comment.

Comment: Fixer1234: The SOLUTION is offered in the video obviously. The video link is provided to show people what they are looking for instead of describing everything in hopes that they get it right. The other information is just that... information. Since people have not posted ANYTHING that corrected the problem I thought people would appreciate an actual solution that shows HOW to fix it.

Comment: So on to better things. I tried the blow dryer solution and as expected it did NOT work. I then dismantled the laptop and did the reflow and it worked great once I put it back together. I highly suggest trying that if nothing else has worked. There is a LOT of information out there now that covers this repair and the cause. Feel like HP should have done a recall but that would be admitting something was wrong and cost them to much. Good luck to all. :)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  Just FYI, the site is a knowledge base of solutions.  In this format, content should be self-contained in the answer, rather than linking to a solution somewhere else.  Videos really don't fit.  To be useful, the essential information should be incorporated into the answer and the video can be linked for attribution and reference.  Also, answers should focus on the actual (proven) solution rather than a lot of commentary or opinion.  The site is different from a forum.  It might be useful to take the quick [tour](http://superuser.com/tour).